# Stream min() and max() method in Lambda Expression with Comparator , returns first and last element only does not return min/max element

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Stream `min()` and `max()` method in Lambda Expression with Comparator, returns first and the last element only, does not return min/max element.
Can anyone explain the working of min() and `max()`.

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add(0);
        al.add(5);
        al.add(10);
        al.add(15);
        al.add(20);
        al.add(25);

        System.out.println(al);

        Integer l = al.stream()
                            .min((a, b) -> -a.compareTo(b))
                            .get();
        System.out.println(l);

        Integer l2 = al.stream()
                            .max((a, b) -> -a.compareTo(b))
                            .get();
        System.out.println(l2);
    }
}
```

Output: 25 and 0 respectively

Comment: You're negating the comparison result your elements. That explains why `min` returns the actual maximum and `max` returns the actual minimum. First and last are not accidental, your list is sorted.

Comment: Just in case if you use `.mapToInt(Integer::intValue).summaryStatistics()`, you can get back `min`, `max`, `avg`, etc

Comment: Hi Team, min and max accepts Comparator as an argument. so wrote the Descending order lambda expression which mean now {25, 20,15,10,5,0} .Now min and max method should perform operation on this so the output should be 0 the 25, but i am getting different result. So if i am missing the working of min and max please explain that.

Comment: its a Comparator Lambda Expression , please find the formated code         Comparator<Integer> cc = (a, b) -> -a.compareTo(b);

        Integer l = al.stream().min(cc).get();
        System.out.println(l);

        Integer l2 = al.stream().max(cc).get();
        System.out.println(l2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the method reference of `compareTo` without specifying `a` and `b` for comparison:

Make

```java
al.stream().min((a, b) -> -a.compareTo(b))
```

be

```java
al.stream().min(Integer::compareTo).get();
```

You have used this method (`compareTo`) of the `Comparable` `Integer` here, but you have negated the result which *reverses* the output to the complement of the desired one.

`a.compareTo(b)` returns either a positive number (1 most likely) if `a` is greater than `b`, if they are equal the result will be 0 and if `b > a` you get a negative result. Since you have negated it, the order result will be the exact opposite of what you wanted (`min` ⇒ `max` and `max` ⇒ `min`).

Comment: min and max accepts Comparator as an argument. so wrote the Descending order lambda expression which mean now {25, 20,15,10,5,0} .Now min and max method should perform operation on this so the output should be 0 the 25, but i am getting different result. So if i am missing the working of min and max please explain that.

Comment: @Kim You did not use a `Comparator` but the method `compareTo` of a class that `implements Comparable` (`Integer` in this case)... The method reference from my answer doesn't care about order in the collection. Does it work for you?

Comment: what you are saying that's fine and that is working but, i am not satisfied as i am passing the revers order of the ArrayList and in the base of that min/max should return value. i modified what i wanted to say          Comparator<Integer> cc = (a, b) -> -a.compareTo(b);

        Integer l = al.stream().min(cc).get();
        System.out.println(l);

        Integer l2 = al.stream().max(cc).get();
        System.out.println(l2);

Comment: @Kim What you have done is implementing a custom comparator that uses the **negated** comparison method of a `Comparable` (`compareTo`), which leads to the complement of the desired output. `min` gives the the actual maximum and vice versa.

Comment: okay, now it clear the doubt, it means it compared using the negative value and on basis of that returned the output. Please feel free correct me, Can you please elaborate this in your answer so that i can accept this. Please

Comment: Negating the result of a comparator is only **almost** a reverse comparator. If a comparator happens to return `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, negating it will overflow and result in `Integer.MIN_VALUE` again. A safe reverse comparator would be `(a, b) -> b.compareTo(a)`, but you can also just use the builtin `Comparator.reverseOrder()`. Likewise, you can use the builtin `Comparator.naturalOrder()` instead of `Integer::compareTo`.